# a list inside a list - django views

Tags: django

```
{% if latest_question_list %}
<ul>
{% for question in latest_question_list %}
    <li><a href="/polls/{{ question.id }}/">{{ question.question_text }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
{% else %}
   <p>No polls are available.</p>
{% endif %}
```

and I have

```
def index(request):
latest_question_list = Question.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
template = loader.get_template('polls/index.html')
context = RequestContext(request, {
    'latest_question_list': latest_question_list,
})
return HttpResponse(template.render(context))
```

But how do I do an inner list?

Since its a list of lists how do I define the lists in such a way that they can be access correctly? The question model certainly doesn't contain any list of comments. I can do a  query but I really have no idea where to begin here.

Thanks for any suggestion.

edit: 
 have a list of questions from the database. The code above lets me view them just fine. But every list has multiple comments. How do I list all the comments per question? I need another for loop in the html but I am not sure how to give each question its own data in the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't at all a question about lists.

Presumably you have a separate Comment model, and that model has a ForeignKey to the Question model; if you don't have that structure, then you should.

Then it's simply a matter of following the reverse relationship for each question:

```
{% for question in latest_question_list %}
    ...
    {% for comment in question.comment_set.all %}
        {{ comment.text }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Note that this exact structure is well described in the tutorial, with the example of Poll and Choice.

Comment: Thank you very much! I knew I had to be making this way more complex than it needed to be. Sorry I am new to django.

Comment: Quick question. How do I add a form for each question so a user can post  comment.